# To get the object of the selected option of dropdown using values

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a dropdown and I need to get the entire  object using the value. I can get it using the text with contains but the same does not work by value. Here is my code. What am I doing wrong?

```js
//var option = $("#car option:contains('Volvo')");
//alert(option.attr('value'));

var option = $("#car option:contains('value1')");
alert(option.attr('value'));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id="car">
  <option value="value1">Volvo</option>
  <option value="value2">Saab</option>
  <option value="value3">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="value4">Audi</option>
</select>
```

The commented portion works fine. I need to find a way to get the entire object using the value instead.

Comment: just use your variable `option`

Comment: `var option = $("#car option[value = 'value1']");`

Comment: @Saksham the option is not working and so my question.

Comment: @Mohamed-Yousef If you could post it as an answer, I can upvote as I think the other answer seems to use the same code as yours.

Comment: @Testing123 I posted it as answer

Comment: To get the Select value in jQuery: $( "#id" ).val();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While `:contains` selector select elements that contain the specified text. You can use `[attribute = "value"]` .. I highly recommended to read about [Selectors Here](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/the-30-css-selectors-you-must-memorize--net-16048)

```js
//var option = $("#car option:contains('Volvo')");
//alert(option.attr('value'));

var option = $("#car option[value='value1']");
alert(option.attr('value'));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id="car">
  <option value="value1">Volvo</option>
  <option value="value2">Saab</option>
  <option value="value3">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="value4">Audi</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
//var option = $("#car option:contains('Volvo')");
//alert(option.attr('value'));

var option = $("#car option[value=value1]");
alert(option.attr('value'));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="car">
  <option value="value1">Volvo</option>
  <option value="value2">Saab</option>
  <option value="value3">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="value4">Audi</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that jQuery :contains refer only to the text node of the element,not the content of an attribute.

you can use selector of an attribute in the following way:

```
var option = $("#car option[value=value1]");
alert(option.attr('value'));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var e = document.getElementById("car");
var selectedOption = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
alert(selectedOption);
```

First you target the selection list element with variable `e`, then you use the state of that element and assign it to `selectedOption`.

Comment: I got my answer below but your code has this error selectedOption.attr is not a function

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.